# How to Fix This CSS3 Validation Error

Tags: css

I have this in my CSS file:

```
#text p {text-shadow: 0px 1px 0pt rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) }
```

But when I check it against CSS3 I get this error:

Value Error : text-shadow Too many values or values are not recognized : 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5 )

How to fix it please without altering the effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read this article: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-validation/

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the W3C validator not recognizing `rgba` (if you just use `rgb(0, 0, 0)` it validates properly). I wouldn't worry.

On a side note, why did you use "pt" on the third parameter? You could just leave it as 0:

```
#text p { text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) }
```

Comment: I wish people would stop trying to validate HTML5 and CSS3 code for the next year or so. It makes no sense to validate things that haven't been standardized yet (why do the W3C even have a validator for it in the first place?). I'm also getting tired of answering questions with "this is a bug and you can't/shouldn't change it".

Answer (score 0):

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textshadow.html), `text-shadow` takes 4 parameters. Maybe try to move rgba to the first place? also please note that in 0px 1px there are px but for the third one you use pt.

Anyway i have created [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNZuQ/1/) and it seems that it works, not sure why it does not validate...

Answer (score 0):

yes, try

```
#text p {text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) }
```

Comment: Same output. :( Thanks for the try